# Timestamp for LaTeXmk output

Tags: latexmk

I am running `latexmk` in a *silent* and *preview continuous* mode.

```
latexmk -pdf -silent -pvc myfile.tex
```

However when I look at the terminal (which has brief log output), then I have no way to figure out the time(s) at which the file was compiled. In other words I would like a line

> last compiled at Wed Sep 26 21:18:53 IST 2018

This is useful for me to trace the working version (in case of errors) from the backup sets.

I can write a small bash script, which will watch the file for update and then call `pdflatex` in *batchmode* and then print output with date. (Grep for errors/warning in the aux/log and print message accordingly.) However isnt it nothing but duplicating the `latexmk`?

-- Mike

Comment: Is the time stamp of the last compilation enough? You could retrieve this from the first line of the .log file.

Comment: I want it printed *along with* the other output of `latexmk`.

Comment: Send a feature request to the maintainer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First failed attempt:

In `~/.latexmkrc` file:

```
$latex = "date;latex --src-specials";
```

Doesnt work :-

---

Second failed attempt (I am giving it here, as this may give an idea of simpler / alternate solution to someone!)

```
latexmk -silent -pvc -e 'print "Last compiled at: ".localtime()."\n";' myfile.tex
```

From the manpage:

> ```
>   -e <code>
>           Execute the specified initialization code before processing.  
>           The code is Perl code of the same form as is  used  in  latexmk's
>           initialization files.  For more details, see the information on the 
>           -r option, and the section about "Configuration/initialization (RC)
>           files".  The code is typically a sequence of assignment statements
>           separated by semicolons.
> ```

However this prints the required string only at the beginning. I believe that by modifying certain variables, like `$latex`, one can achieve what is needed.

---

The following is a **complete working solution**. The only catch is it needs root permission (or make a local copy the script).

Insert the following code in the `latexmk` script:

```
$datestring = localtime();
print "Last compiled at: $datestring\n";
```

These lines to be included in the function which actually calls `$latex`:

```
sub rdb_primary_run
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to modify `latexmk` to get this effect, but just configure it.  The following in a latexmkrc file will do the job

```
$pdflatex = 'internal mylatex pdflatex %O %S';
sub mylatex {
   my $ret = system @_;
   print "Last compilation at ", scalar(localtime()), "\n";
   return $ret;
}
```

You can make similar definitions for the `$latex`, `$lualatex` and `$xelatex` variables.

Comment: As this looks more like a system programming (or is it perl?), can you please care to explain the code or give some poiinters?

Comment: See the latexmk documentation, in particular the sections on configuration, on how to set variables in initialization files, and on the format of command specifications.  The language is indeed Perl.